# Runtime Null Reference Exception Using SimpleInjector in WebApi Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, simple-injector

In my MVC project, I have an API controller that I want to use dependency injection for.  I am using [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html) for dependency injection.

Here is my api controller:

```
public class MedicInfoesApiController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IDiContext _dbContext;

    public MedicInfoesApiController() { }

    public MedicInfoesApiController(IDiContext diContext)
    {
        _dbContext = diContext;
    }

    // POST: api/MedicInfoesApi
    [ResponseType(typeof(MedicInfo))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostMedicInfo(MedicInfo medicInfo)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // Create empty Employee Object to get info of person being submitted via IBM
        Employee emp = new Employee();

        //check if IBM that user is submitting exists
        if (!EmployeeData.IsValidIBM(medicInfo.MedicIbm))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "This IBM does not exist!");
        }
        // Check if any existing IBM's match what the user is trying to submit... if none then save to database
        else if (_dbContext.GainAccess().MedicInfoes.Any(x => x.MedicIbm.Equals(medicInfo.MedicIbm, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "This person already exists!");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        else
        {
            // Set empty Employee object with Data of person
            emp = EmployeeData.GetEmployee(medicInfo.MedicIbm);
            medicInfo.Active = true;
            _dbContext.GainAccess().MedicInfoes.Add(medicInfo);

            _dbContext.GainAccess().SaveChanges();
        }
```

When debugging, the runtime error is occurring on the `else if` statement stating:

> x.MedicIbm=error CS0103: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context

and

> _dbContext=null

Can dependency injection be used with api controllers?  I assumed they could?

Any explanation or help as to why this is happening is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide your DI Registration where you add this dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default constructor is being called, so the context is not being injected. Hence the *null*

Remove the default constructor from the `ApiController` and keep the follow

```
public MedicInfoesApiController(IDiContext diContext) {
    _dbContext = diContext;
}
```

also ensure that the `IDiContext` is properly registered with the DI container

Reference [ASP.NET Web API Integration Guide for Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html?highlight=web%20api#asp-net-web-api-integration-guide)

Comment: Okay, that was my initial thought.  I understand the Null Reference Exception, but if I comment that out, then I receive runtime console errors: `"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MedicInfoesApiController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."`... `"Type 'AviationMedicTraining.Controllers.ApiControllers.MedicInfoesApiController' does not have a default constructor"`

Comment: That is a default error message and does not mean what you think it does. That message is when the framework is unable to create the controller while resolving its dependencies. Did you review the second part of the answer.

Comment: Hi @M12Bennett, please follow the ASP.NET Web API integration Guide for Simple Injector, as Nkosi referred to. Without replacing the default `DependencyResolver` with Simple Injector's `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver`, Simple Injector will not be invoked by Web API.

Comment: Perfect.  I apologize, I didn't use the bottom of your answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, just had something happen again.. so now my api controller method is being hit as expected, but now the record is not being added/saved to the database. I've edited my code to show

Comment: @M12Bennett That is a new problem separate to the original issue. That would require a new question.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks